# Wordpress Bio/Image Widget - Stacked caption at full size, side-by-side at smaller

Tags: html, wordpress, css, responsive-design

I feel silly asking something that seems so rudimentary, but I just can't figure this out.

I've got a Wordpress theme with a side bar. I want to put a simple author bio on the side (an image with a bit of text and a link underneath).

When the theme responds down, this sidebar drops below the main content area and gets HUGE, so I'd like for the layout to switch to a smaller image on the left and text on the right.

It seems simple, but various code I've been trying to write or grab off the internet still isn't working.

Here's the HTML and CSS I've been trying so far:

```
<div id="bioblock">
  <img id="bioimg" src="via.placeholder.com/600x600" alt="Blog Author" style="width:100%; margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <div id="bioblurb">
    <h3>Welcome to My Blog</h3>     
    <p>This is a bit about the blog and the author. It will be several lines long.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#bioblock {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #bioblock { display: block; width: 50%;}
  #bioblock #bioimg {height: auto; display: inline; float: left;}
  #bioblock #bioblurb { float: right; } 
}
```

I tried to find a preexisting widget out there to handle this, but the author bio widgets are awful and the image + caption ones don't seem to solve it.

I'd love any help anyone could offer. I'm sure I've made a bazillion dumb errors here, please don't laugh too hard at my code. Feel free to burn my stupid code attempt to the ground and suggest another way to do this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the text to float around the image (i.e. also go under it), you should use `display: inline-block` for both the image and the text container, both with fixed width (meaning percentages or pixels, choosen so that both can fit into the parent element side by side). And it's good to use some other settings too, see below.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #bioblock {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
  }
  #bioblock #bioimg {
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35% !important;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  #bioblock #bioblurb {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="bioblock">
  <img id="bioimg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x600" alt="Blog Author" style="width:100%; margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <div id="bioblurb">
    <h3>Welcome to My Blog</h3>
    <p>This is a bit about the blog and the author. It will be several lines long.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! This solved my issues perfectly. Time to dissect this and see where I went wrong :)